# android error in style : no resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, styles

i want to do when user press on night/day mode the mode of day to nigh and vice versa can change,after googling i found following :

```
       <style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
              <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>
              <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
              <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
              <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_light</item>
              <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_light</item>
              <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
      </style>

      <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
             <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Dark</item>
             <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
             <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
             <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_dark</item>
             <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_dark</item>
             <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
     </style>
```

but i got error **no resource found that matches the given name** in  following :

```
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_light</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_light</item>
```

and in

```
    <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconToggle">@drawable/ic_menu_toggle_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="menuIconShare">@drawable/ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
```

so please help me what i forget.

my menifest file :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ="com.example.daynight"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.daynight.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Put `android:` prefix in your `item name` . like so  `<item name="android:menuIconCamera">@drawable/ic_menu_camera_holo_dark</item>` and try

Comment: no , i try that it not possible

Comment: then try as per @Golu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light` appears to have been added in API Level 14.Do below steps

Package Explorer, select Properties, select Android, and set Project Build Target to API level 14 or higher.
and

**manifest**

android:minSdkVersion="8" to android:minSdkVersion="14"

Comment: do one more thing clean your project

Comment: please test in your device ?? so got proper peoblem answers

Comment: @nikiIgeniusDev ic_menu_camera_holo_light is this ur image and is it here on drawable ?

Comment: then what about : <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item> and <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>

Comment: @android:color/background_dark belongs to your android

Comment: means i have lower version thant it ?

Comment: also check your target version on project properties

Comment: @nikiIgeniusDev target=android-19 project.properites check this file on ur project

Answer (score 0):

No Resource Found means it can not find the image in ./res/drawable

Comment: then what about  : <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_dark</item>  and <item name="listDragShadowBackground">@android:color/background_light</item>